# issue when fixing element to top

Tags: jquery, css, css-position, fixed, absolute

I'm adding a few new features into a friend of mines website, which is already built. He wants a a div, which is a little bit bellow the header, to be locked to the screen as soon a the user scrolls to the top of it. I created the function bellow which works just fine, but as soon as jquery places the element in a fixed position, all of the elements bellow it slide up causing the entire site to "jump". Is there a way to prevent this from happening without placing all of these elements in an absolute position? This website is pretty involved and will take a lot to redo all of these elements.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    function lockelem() {

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 786) 
          $('.tabs').css({'z-index': '10000', 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-200px', 'width': '100%'}); 
        else
          $('.tabs').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'});
        }

   $(window).scroll(lockelem);
   lockelem();
});
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer is almost correct.  It won't quite work because the else statement won't hide the placeholder div in time.  You need this:

```
function lockelem() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > $('#tabs').position().top ) {
          $('#tabs').css({'z-index': '10000', 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '0', 'width': '100%'});
        $("#tabPlaceholder").show();
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < $('#tabPlaceholder').position().top ) {
          $('#tabs').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'});
          $('#tabPlaceholder').hide();
    }   
}
lockelem();
$(window).scroll(lockelem);
```

Working fiddle, you may need to resize the window to make it small enough to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/rlouie/j7hsX/

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my site. The easiest solution I found was to just create a "spacer" div directly before it.

When the main div is in flow (position:static/relative) the spacer div is hidden. Once the main div comes out of flow (fixed) I show the spacer div. Here's some code:

```
jQuery(function($) {
function lockelem() {

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 786) 
      $('.tabs').css({'z-index': '10000', 'position': 'fixed', 'top': '-200px', 'width': '100%'}); 
      //Here we show the Spacer and set its height (just in case you don't know the height of the div before runtime
      $('.tabsSpacer').css({height:$('.tabsSpacer').next().height()+'px'}).show();
    else
      $('.tabs').css({'position': 'relative', 'top': 'auto'});
      //hide the spacer
      $('.tabsSpacer').hide();
    }

   $(window).scroll(lockelem);
   lockelem();
});
```

If you don't feel like giving it its own class or whatever you can just refer to it as the element directly before the main div with `.prev()`. The actual implementation is up to you, but that's the general solution I found.

Without knowing what your actual html structure is, it might look something like this:

```
<div class="tabsSpacer" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="tabs">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Elements with absolute or fixed position always get removed from the document flow, which is causing the jump. I find that the most reliable way to account for that is to duplicate the element and use the duplicate as your fixed header. This is better than using a spacer or adding extra padding somewhere or anything that has a potential to be off even a little. This way there's no chance of your original content moving at all, since you never really touch the original content.

As an aside, I also find that keeping the styles in the CSS and just having JS add or remove classes is a much cleaner way to manipulate things. It's saved me a ton of headaches.

You can see a generic example of a sticky header here: http://jsfiddle.net/8SB5Z/

For your code, I'd do this:

**JS**

```
jQuery(function($) {

   // Clone the header
   $('.tabs').clone().addClass('clone').insertAfter('.tabs');

   // Add or remove the 'visible' class on the clone as needed
   function lockelem() {
       if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 786 ) {
          $('.tabs.clone').addClass('visible');
       } else {
          $('.tabs.clone').removeClass('visible');
       }
   }

   // Check the positioning on scroll
   $(window).scroll(lockelem);
   lockelem();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.tabs.clone {
   z-index: 10000;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   display:none;
}
.tabs.clone.visible {
   display:block;
}
```